# how to deal with changing reference locations when linking?

Tags: excel

I have data linked to specific cells in one excel sheet(worksheetA) referenced from another sheet(worksheetB). Sometimes I may insert rows and change the location of data in worksheetB while worksheetA is closed.
When I open worksheetA after changing worksheetB the data does not link to the new reference locations(still links to the old ones)

Is there something that I should be doing differently?
How can i make it so the links get updated even if worksheetA is closed?

Comment: You could add named ranges to the file where the data is located and make the linked file target those names. [Tutorial](https://trumpexcel.com/named-ranges-in-excel/)

Comment: ok thanks i think that could work but but be some work to set up. What about what copying and pasting a named range? how do you paste the link to other sheet without having to manually type the named range?

Comment: Maybe if you add some examples, we could help you more precisely.